# Anyone heard of this game?

Tags: poker-history

We play a poker game called 'bastard' you get 3 cards, face down and three cards are face up on table. You make the best hand using only 3 cards. You either keep your hand,  play what's on the table or choose one card from the up cards. Is this the right name for this game? Can't find it anywhere. Was wanting to know if you only use three cards and are playing it if it were a "real" hand then wouldn't three of a kind be like having 4 of a kind?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the name but be aware of the order of hands
[Count Outcomes Three Card Poker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175976/count-outcomes-in-three-card-poker)

1. Straight Flush
2. Three of a Kind
3. Straight
4. Flush
5. Pair
6. High Card